# Double loop with django Templates

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

so I have this matrix sent to a view

```
[[6.197, 6.156, 6.165, 6.164, 4.741], [6.191, 6.106, 6.175, 6.132, 4.741], [6.158, 6.137, 6.137, 6.133, 4.741]]
```

and a list containing dates

```
["11-12-2016","12-12-2016","13-12-2016"]
```

and I want to format them with Template to look like this

```
 [["11-12-2016",6.197, 6.156, 6.165, 6.164, 4.741]
  ["12-12-2016",6.191, 6.106, 6.175, 6.132, 4.741]
....]
```

Iam using this code :

```
 {% for date in dates %}

        {% with forloop.counter0 as i %}

      ,["{{date}}"{% for item in selling.i %} ,{{item}} {% endfor %}]
         {% endwith %}
      {% endfor %}
```

and it doesn't work , but when I replace i with 0,1.. the second loop works fine on one list

Comment: If you have a new question you should add it as a new question, your update invalidated the original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{% for item in selling.i %}
```

This isn't going to work -- the template will look for an attribute or index literally equal to "i", and not the value of that variable.

The Django template language actively discourages using too much logic in the template, and this is an example of something you can't do.

So create the lists as you want them in Python, and pass those to the template. E.g. in Python

```
combined = [[str(date)] + sell for date, sell in zip(dates, selling)]
```

And in the template

```
{% for row in combined %}
  [{{ row|join:","|safe }}],
{% endfor %}
```